# How can I open a modal using react-leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, bootstrap-modal, react-leaflet

I am trying to use the library react-leaflet and I want to open a modal when we click on a button on the popup but I do not achieve to do that.

Here is my code :

```
import React from "react";
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import { defaultMarker } from "./defaultMarker";
import { popupContent, popupHead, popupText, okText } from "./popupStyles";
import "./Map.css";

const center = [51.505, -0.09];

const MapComp = () => {
  return (
    <Map style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh" }} center={center} zoom={13}>
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      <Marker position={center} icon={defaultMarker}>
        <Popup className="request-popup">
          <button>Open Modal</button>
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
      }
    </Map>
  );
};

export default MapComp;
```

You can see the full code there :

https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-style-the-react-leaflet-popup-forked-7yozy?file=/src/Map.js:0-788

I just open a modal when I click on the popup and I click on the button "Open Modal"

Thank you very much !

Comment: There is no modal code anywhere. How do you expect it to show up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `react-bootstrap` which includes react components for bootstrap library or `reactstrap`. Both makes it easier to play with bootstrap components otherwise you will have to create your own and manipulate the state by yourself.

Here is an example with `react-bootstrap`:

Install the library `npm i react-bootstrap`

Create a Modal component:

```
function CustomModal({ show, onClose }) {
  return (
    <Modal show={show} onHide={onClose}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={onClose}>
          Close
        </Button>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={onClose}>
          Save Changes
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

On your Map import your custom modal and handle its state to be able to show hide it upon button press

```
const MapComp = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Map style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh" }} center={center} zoom={13}>
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
        <Marker position={center} icon={defaultMarker}>
          <Popup className="request-popup">
            <button onClick={() => setShow(true)}>Open Modal</button>
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </Map>
      <Modal show={show} onClose={handleClose} />
    </>
  );
};
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-do-to-open-a-modal-using-react-leaflet-2pp8y?file=/src/Map.js)

**Edit**

It seems that there is a bug with `react-bootstrap` library. When you open the modal and then you close it, the map freezes unexpectedly and you cannot interact with it.

I installed and reproduced it with `reactstrap` and there is no such an issue.