# Need to open a Modal on Leaflet marker.bindPopup()

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, modal-dialog, popup

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-hoalWLoI8r4UszCkZ5kL8vayOGVae1oxXe/2A4AO6J9+580uKHDO3JdHb7NzwwzK5xr/Fs0W40kiNHxM9vyTtQ==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-BB3hKbKWOc9Ez/TAwyWxNXeoV9c1v6FIeYiBieIWkpLjauysF18NzgR1MBNBXf8/KABdlkX68nAhlwcDFLGPCQ==" crossorigin=""></script>

  <!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://atorinfriul.netsons.org/html/js/magnific-popup.css">
  <style >

    .mappa_global{max-width: 1350px;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 85vh;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 25px;
      padding-left: 2%;
      padding-right: 2%;
      margin: 0px auto;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;}

  .mfp-no-margins img.mfp-img {
    padding: 0;
  }

  .mfp-no-margins .mfp-figure:after {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .mfp-no-margins .mfp-container {
    padding: 0;
  }




  .mfp-with-zoom .mfp-container,
  .mfp-with-zoom.mfp-bg {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  }

  .mfp-with-zoom.mfp-ready .mfp-container {
        opacity: 1;
  }
  .mfp-with-zoom.mfp-ready.mfp-bg {
        opacity: 0.8;
  }

  .mfp-with-zoom.mfp-removing .mfp-container,
  .mfp-with-zoom.mfp-removing.mfp-bg {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  </style>

</head>
<!-- indispensabile onload per caricare lo script dei video nella hero -->
<body  class="my_width">


  <div class="">
    <a class="image-popup-no-margins" href="http://www.ertoecasso.it/immagini/erto/viuzza.jpg"  title="Una delle stradine del centro storico. Il tempo pare essersi fermato.">          <img src="http://www.ertoecasso.it/immagini/erto/viuzza.jpg" style="width:150px;" alt="Responsive image">        </a>
<p>Modal based on https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ </p>
  </div>

<div>
<div class="p25_bis">
  <div id="map_canvas" class="mappa_global" class="lazyload" ></div>
</div>
<script>


var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>';
var mbUrl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw';

var Streets = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/streets-v11', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr});

var Osm = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 19,
attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
});

var Esri_NatGeoWorldMap = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/NatGeo_World_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; National Geographic, Esri, DeLorme, NAVTEQ, UNEP-WCMC, USGS, NASA, ESA, METI, NRCAN, GEBCO, NOAA, iPC',
maxZoom: 16
});

var OpenTopoMap = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 17,
attribution: 'Map data: &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpenTopoMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)'
});

var Stamen_Toner = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.{ext}', {
attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
subdomains: 'abcd',
minZoom: 0,
maxZoom: 20,
ext: 'png'
});

var mymap = L.map('map_canvas', {
center: [46.09067427290000, 13.36360216140000],
zoom: 9,
layers: [Stamen_Toner]
});

var baseLayers = {
'Toner': Stamen_Toner,
'OpenTopoMap': OpenTopoMap,
'OpenStreetMap': Osm,
'Streets': Streets,
'National Geographic': Esri_NatGeoWorldMap
};

var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(mymap);

  var myIcon2 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/images/marker-icon.png',
      iconSize: [40, 40], // size of the icon
      });


      // arrivo Percorso
      var marker = L.marker([46.190472, 12.576231], {icon: myIcon2}).addTo(mymap);
      marker.bindPopup('<a class="image-popup-no-margins" href="http://www.ertoecasso.it/immagini/erto/viuzza.jpg"  title="Una delle stradine del centro storico. Il tempo pare essersi fermato.">          <img src="http://www.ertoecasso.it/immagini/erto/viuzza.jpg" style="width:150px;" alt="Responsive image">        </a>');

</script>


</div>





<!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ or Zepto.js 1.0+ -->
<script src="https://atorinfriul.netsons.org/html/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
<script src="https://atorinfriul.netsons.org/html/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.image-popup-no-margins').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    closeBtnInside: false,
    fixedContentPos: true,
    mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
    image: {
      verticalFit: true
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: true,
      duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
    }
  });

});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I need to do something like this:
[How can I open a modal using react-leaflet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66025873/how-can-i-open-a-modal-using-react-leaflet)
Unfortunatly I can't make it work with my needings, too bad in coding.

Example code shows a working modal when clicking on first image. I need to replicate same effect on leaflet map using marker.bindPopup()

Modal experience is based on https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ pluging

```
    marker.bindPopup('<a class="image-popup-no-margins" href="http://www.ertoecasso.it/immagini/erto/viuzza.jpg"  title="Una delle stradine del centro storico. Il tempo pare essersi fermato.">          <img src="http://www.ertoecasso.it/immagini/erto/viuzza.jpg" style="width:150px;" alt="Responsive image">        </a>');

here is script used to launch modal

    
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.image-popup-no-margins').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    closeBtnInside: false,
    fixedContentPos: true,
    mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
    image: {
      verticalFit: true
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: true,
      duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
    }
  });

});
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-hoalWLoI8r4UszCkZ5kL8vayOGVae1oxXe/2A4AO6J9+580uKHDO3JdHb7NzwwzK5xr/Fs0W40kiNHxM9vyTtQ==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-BB3hKbKWOc9Ez/TAwyWxNXeoV9c1v6FIeYiBieIWkpLjauysF18NzgR1MBNBXf8/KABdlkX68nAhlwcDFLGPCQ==" crossorigin=""></script>

  <!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://atorinfriul.netsons.org/html/js/magnific-popup.css">
  <style >

    .mappa_global{max-width: 1350px;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 85vh;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 25px;
      padding-left: 2%;
      padding-right: 2%;
      margin: 0px auto;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;}

  .mfp-no-margins img.mfp-img {
    padding: 0;
  }

  .mfp-no-margins .mfp-figure:after {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .mfp-no-margins .mfp-container {
    padding: 0;
  }




  .mfp-with-zoom .mfp-container,
  .mfp-with-zoom.mfp-bg {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  }

  .mfp-with-zoom.mfp-ready .mfp-container {
        opacity: 1;
  }
  .mfp-with-zoom.mfp-ready.mfp-bg {
        opacity: 0.8;
  }

  .mfp-with-zoom.mfp-removing .mfp-container,
  .mfp-with-zoom.mfp-removing.mfp-bg {
    opacity: 0;
  }

.hover-title {
display: inline;
pointer-events: auto;
cursor: pointer;
}

.hover-image {
    visibility: hidden;
}

body:not(.mobile) .hover-title:hover + .hover-image {
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.hover-image {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

/* Change width and height to scale images */
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vh;
}

.hover-image img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    max-height: 100% !important;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}


  </style>

</head>
<!-- indispensabile onload per caricare lo script dei video nella hero -->
<body  class="my_width">






<div>
<div class="p25_bis">
  <div id="map_canvas" class="mappa_global" class="lazyload" ></div>
</div>
<script>


var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>';
var mbUrl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw';

var Streets = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/streets-v11', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr});

var Osm = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 19,
attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
});

var Esri_NatGeoWorldMap = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/NatGeo_World_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; National Geographic, Esri, DeLorme, NAVTEQ, UNEP-WCMC, USGS, NASA, ESA, METI, NRCAN, GEBCO, NOAA, iPC',
maxZoom: 16
});

var OpenTopoMap = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 17,
attribution: 'Map data: &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpenTopoMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)'
});

var Stamen_Toner = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.{ext}', {
attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
subdomains: 'abcd',
minZoom: 0,
maxZoom: 20,
ext: 'png'
});

var mymap = L.map('map_canvas', {
center: [46.09067427290000, 13.36360216140000],
zoom: 9,
layers: [Stamen_Toner]
});

var baseLayers = {
'Toner': Stamen_Toner,
'OpenTopoMap': OpenTopoMap,
'OpenStreetMap': Osm,
'Streets': Streets,
'National Geographic': Esri_NatGeoWorldMap
};

var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(mymap);

  var myIcon2 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/images/marker-icon.png',
      iconSize: [40, 40], // size of the icon
      });


      // arrivo Percorso
      var marker = L.marker([46.190472, 12.576231], {icon: myIcon2}).addTo(mymap);
      marker.bindPopup('<a class="image-popup-no-margins hover-title" href="https://motoguzzi850gtcalifornia1973home.files.wordpress.com/2022/11/img_0718.jpg"    Target="_blank"  title="Ponte Antoi sul lago di Barcis">   <img loading="lazy"  src="https://motoguzzi850gtcalifornia1973home.files.wordpress.com/2022/11/img_0718.jpg" style="width:150px;" alt="Responsive image"></a> <div class="hover-image"><img loading="lazy"  src="https://motoguzzi850gtcalifornia1973home.files.wordpress.com/2022/11/img_0718.jpg" alt="Responsive image"></div>');

</script>


</div>





<!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ or Zepto.js 1.0+ -->
<script src="https://atorinfriul.netsons.org/html/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
<script src="https://atorinfriul.netsons.org/html/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.image-popup-no-margins').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    closeBtnInside: false,
    fixedContentPos: true,
    mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
    image: {
      verticalFit: true
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: true,
      duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
    }
  });

});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Solved!
As I use an anchor for opening image from popover in a new tab, I just neede to style inside Tag  as suggested in
https://support.cargo.site/Show-an-Image-on-Hover

And trick was done, and worked for me

```
<div class="hover-title">Image Hover One</div>
<div class="hover-image">{image 1}</div>

.hover-title {
display: inline;
pointer-events: auto;
cursor: pointer;
}

.hover-image {
    visibility: hidden;
}

body:not(.mobile) .hover-title:hover + .hover-image {
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.hover-image {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: -1;
    pointer-events: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

/* Change width and height to scale images */
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vh;
}

.hover-image img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    max-height: 100% !important;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33377864)